# Insert into dictionary table when reading from .json to sql server tables

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to parse .json file to SQL Server database. I have 3 tables: Booking (store bookings, one booking can have several rooms), Room (store rooms), RoomBookingHistory (store association between Booking and Room).
Here is a .json file example:

```
[
  {
    "BookingName": "Egypt, SES, 3 persons, 14 days",
    "Paid": "0",
    "Active": "1",
    "DateOfBooking": "2020/05/07 19:35:02",
    "UserLogin": "Alex222",
    "Rooms": [
      {
        "RoomName": "SESBR23",
        "Capacity": "2",
        "Price": "120",
        "Stars": "3"
      },
      {
        "RoomName": "SESBR21",
        "Capacity": "1",
        "Price": "60",
        "Stars": "4"
      }
    ],
    "FlightNumber": "FO23465",
    "ManagerLogin": "Manger_Egypt_1"
  },
  {
    "BookingName": "Egypt, Hurgada, 3 persons, 7 days",
    "Paid": "0",
    "Active": "1",
    "DateOfBooking": "2020/05/07 17:35:02",
    "UserLogin": "Super_tourist",
    "Rooms": [
      {
        "RoomName": "HGST45",
        "Capacity": "3",
        "Price": "250",
        "Stars": "5"
      }
    ],
    "FlightNumber": "HR5665",
    "ManagerLogin": "Manger_Egypt_2"
  }
]
```

Using created store procedure I read .json and insert into Booking table Bookings and into Room table Rooms from .json.
During parsing I need to insert into RoomBookingHistory records and associate each Booking with Rooms from file using generated id during writing from .json.

```
RoomBookingHistory
    RoomBookingId   int             not null     identity(1,1),
    RoomId          int,
    BookingId       int
```

How to write sql to insert into RoomBookingHistory correct associated id's?

Here is a code of sp:

```
drop procedure  if exists dbo.usp_ImportBookingData
go
create procedure dbo.usp_ImportBookingData
    @parametrs nvarchar(max)
    
as
begin
    set nocount on

    create table #Booking
    (
            BookingId       int             not null     identity(1,1),
            BookingName     varchar(30),
            Paid            bit,
            Active          bit,
            DateOfBooking   datetime,
            UserId          int,
            FlightId        int,
            ManagerId       int,
            Rooms           nvarchar(max)   
    )

    insert into #Booking
    (       
        BookingName,
        Paid,
        Active,
        DateOfBooking,
        Rooms
    )
    select      
        b.BookingName,
        b.Paid,
        b.Active,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, b.DateOfBooking),
        b.Rooms
    from openjson(@parametrs)
        with
        (
            BookingName         varchar(30)     N'$.BookingName',
            Paid                bit             N'$.Paid',
            Active              bit             N'$.Active',
            DateOfBooking       datetime        N'$.DateOfBooking',
            Rooms               nvarchar(max)   N'$.Rooms' as json
        ) b

    insert into dbo.Booking
    (   
        BookingName,
        Paid,
        Active,
        DateOfBooking
    )
    select
        b.BookingName,
        b.Paid,
        b.Active,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, b.DateOfBooking)
    from #Booking b

    create table #Rooms
    (
        RoomId              int         not null     identity(1,1),
        RoomName            varchar(30),
        Capacity            int,
        Price               int,
        Stars               int,
        HotelId             int
    )

    insert into #Rooms
    (
        RoomName,
        Capacity,
        Price,
        Stars
    )
    select
        br.RoomName,
        br.Capacity,
        br.Price,
        br.Stars
    from #Booking b
    cross apply openjson(b.Rooms)
        with
        (
            RoomName            varchar(30)     N'$.RoomName',
            Capacity            int             N'$.Capacity',
            Price               int             N'$.Price',
            Stars               int             N'$.Stars'

        ) br
    insert into dbo.Room
    (
        RoomName,
        Capacity,
        Price,
        Stars
    )
    select
        br.RoomName,
        br.Capacity,
        br.Price,
        br.Stars
    from #Rooms br
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: How to write sql to insert into RoomBookingHistory correct associated id's?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [`MERGE INTO... OUTPUT INTO...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) syntax which allows you to capture not only the inserted table columns (like [`INSERT INTO... OUTPUT INTO...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)) but also other columns from the table source (unlike `INSERT INTO... OUTPUT INTO...`).

In the code below:

- In the first MERGE statement I use a @table variable to capture the dbo.Booking.BookingId along with the JSON blob for the associated room(s).
- In the second MERGE statement output the BookingId (captured from the first MERGE) and the dbo.Room.RoomId directly into the dbo.RoomBookingHistory table.

```sql
create procedure dbo.usp_ImportBookingData
    @parametrs nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @InsertedBookings table (
        BookingId int not null,
        Rooms nvarchar(max)
    );

    merge into dbo.Booking as Target
    using (
        select BookingName, Paid, Active, DateOfBooking, Rooms
        from openjson(@parametrs) with (
            BookingName         varchar(30)     N'$.BookingName',
            Paid                bit             N'$.Paid',
            Active              bit             N'$.Active',
            DateOfBooking       datetime        N'$.DateOfBooking',
            Rooms               nvarchar(max)   N'$.Rooms' as json
        )
    ) as Source
    on (0=1) -- force "not matched" for insert
    when not matched then
        insert (BookingName, Paid, Active, DateOfBooking)
        values (BookingName, Paid, Active, DateOfBooking)
    output Inserted.BookingId, Source.Rooms into @InsertedBookings;

    merge into dbo.Room as Target
    using (
        select BookingId, RoomName, Capacity, Price, Stars
        from @InsertedBookings
        cross apply openjson(Rooms) with (
            RoomName            varchar(30)     N'$.RoomName',
            Capacity            int             N'$.Capacity',
            Price               int             N'$.Price',
            Stars               int             N'$.Stars'
        )
    ) as Source
    on (0=1) -- force "not matched" for insert
    when not matched then
        insert (RoomName, Capacity, Price, Stars)
        values (RoomName, Capacity, Price, Stars)
    output Inserted.RoomId, Source.BookingId into dbo.RoomBookingHistory (RoomId, BookingId);
end
```

And then using it...

```sql
declare @parametrs nvarchar(max) = N'[
  {
    "BookingName": "Egypt, SES, 3 persons, 14 days",
    "Paid": "0",
    "Active": "1",
    "DateOfBooking": "2020/05/07 19:35:02",
    "UserLogin": "Alex222",
    "Rooms": [
      {
        "RoomName": "SESBR23",
        "Capacity": "2",
        "Price": "120",
        "Stars": "3"
      },
      {
        "RoomName": "SESBR21",
        "Capacity": "1",
        "Price": "60",
        "Stars": "4"
      }
    ],
    "FlightNumber": "FO23465",
    "ManagerLogin": "Manger_Egypt_1"
  },
  {
    "BookingName": "Egypt, Hurgada, 3 persons, 7 days",
    "Paid": "0",
    "Active": "1",
    "DateOfBooking": "2020/05/07 17:35:02",
    "UserLogin": "Super_tourist",
    "Rooms": [
      {
        "RoomName": "HGST45",
        "Capacity": "3",
        "Price": "250",
        "Stars": "5"
      }
    ],
    "FlightNumber": "HR5665",
    "ManagerLogin": "Manger_Egypt_2"
  }
]';

exec dbo.usp_ImportBookingData @parametrs=@parametrs;

select * from dbo.Booking;
select * from dbo.Room;
select * from dbo.RoomBookingHistory;
```

Yields the results...

```
BookingId   BookingName                    Paid  Active DateOfBooking
----------- ------------------------------ ----- ------ -----------------------
1           Egypt, SES, 3 persons, 14 days 0     1      2020-05-07 19:35:02.000
2           Egypt, Hurgada, 3 persons, 7 d 0     1      2020-05-07 17:35:02.000

(2 rows affected)

RoomId      RoomName                       Capacity    Price       Stars
----------- ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
1           SESBR23                        2           120         3
2           SESBR21                        1           60          4
3           HGST45                         3           250         5

(3 rows affected)

RoomBookingId RoomId      BookingId
------------- ----------- -----------
1             1           1
2             2           1
3             3           2

(3 rows affected)
```